# Changing specific values in a list (why one method works and the other does not?)

Tags: python, list, enumerate

If I have a list:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

and I want to change, say all 4's to 'None' like so:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, None, None, 5]
```

I know I can do this with a loop and enumerate:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    if item == 4:
        list[index] = None
```

However, why does this not work?

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if list[i] == 4:
        list[i] = None
```

I know that the enumerate method is better and works but I would have thought that the second method follows a similar logic, albeit iterating over every value and checking whether it is the value we want to change.

I am just trying to better understand the logic of both pieces of code

Comment: It works though. I just tested here and worked all right. Maybe you should provide a better example, or you found a caching problem. You should try deletting your *.pyc files and other cache-related files/folders.

Comment: that is super weird, I have tested it several times and I am not getting the expected result when I thought I would. Gonna try to spot the problem, thanks!

Comment: You could also try using an online interpreter just as a guarantee. Just Google around for "Python online interpreter", i used [this one](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) to test. But i think you are hitting a caching issue, it's kinda common

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I just found that when I use this on its own it works, but when I want to use it in my implementation it only changes the first '4' and leaves the second '4' as it is.

Comment: I actually just noticed that you are using "list" as variable name. It may not be the real issue, but try to  change this name, as list in python refers to the data structure

Comment: Turns out I broke the loop before all of the instances of the value were found. Thank you for your help but I just don goofed

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I closed the loop before all values were iterated through.